# How can i check if the user is logged out in facebook ( Fb Sdk )

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently develop a facebook application.
now i implemened a sign_in functionallity with the facebook sdk.

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

But how can i check if the user is signed out from facebook. Because i get a exception when i push open graph actions to facebook with a invalid access token.

I am new to javascript and also new to coffee script but i understand it a littble bit.
Thx for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to events using the Javascript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

The event you're looking for is called `auth.logout`.

Comment: Thx the Fb.Event and FB.getLoginStatus from the reference worked  for me correctly .